# How to Validate date using the Class Pattern?

Tags: java

I made this code with my simple knowledge of using the Class Pattern (java.util.regex.Pattern).  Of course it returns true for all the real dates from `0000-00-00` to `9999-12-31`. But unfortunately it still return true for `2013-22-01,2013-01-99`, . . .etc. Help me to validate it correctly.

```
String regex = "([0-9]){4}+([-])?([0-2]){2}+([-])?([0-9]){2}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textFieldName.getText());
return matcher.find();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use Pattern and not DateFormat?

Answer (score 1):

While using DateFormat would be *vastly superior*, [this](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%28%5B0-9%5D%29%7B4%7D%28-%5B0-1%5D%5B1-9%5D-%5B0-1%5D%5B1-9%5D%29&str=2013-12-01) will get you pointed in the right direction.

What `([0-9]){4}(-[0-1][1-2]-([0-2][1-9]|3[0-1]))` does is explained on Debuggex, but here's the quick and dirty runthrough.

- Allow four groups of a digit 0-9.
- Provide an implicit dash.
- Allow a group of either 0 or 1.
- Allow a group of 1-2.
- Provide an implicit dash.
- Either:

  - Allow a group of a digit 0-2 and 1-9, or
  - Allow a group of an implicit 3 and 0-1.

You'll get fun dates for February, but by and large this will get you in the right direction.  A little bit more Regex trickery and you can cover all months and leap-years.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: I assume that for some reason you can't use `DateFormat` class, which is the simplest thing to match date formats.

A way to do it is to provide the list of things that can match. For example, for the months you want either "0 and a digit from 1 to 9", or "1 and a digit from 0 to 2"

That would be done like this (just for the months part):

```
(0[1-9]|1[0-2])
```

This should give you an idea of how to complete your regular expression.

Unfortunately, for the days, it's more complicated, since the number of days vary from a day to another. What should do is just match 2 integers and then take the group from the matcher with the `Matcher.group(int)` method and validate the value by hand.

Another way is to get rid of all that, and simply split on "-" with `String.split(String)`. Then you check you have three subparts, that they can all be parsed to integer, and that their value are consistent. But it's just for the fun: you should really use `DateFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression

```
String reg = "\\^(19|20)\\d\\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$";
```

[Refference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html)

Comment: Why'd you include forward slashes?

Comment: it's a generic expresion for date pattern

Answer (score 0):

try

```
boolean matches = s.matches("\\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])");
```

it's possible to make it know how many days each month has but it's impossible to make regex aware of leap years

Answer (score -1):

Based of what you have already:

```
String regex = "([0-9]){4}+([-])?([0-1][0-2])+([-])?([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])";
```

Comment: Doesn't match 2013-01-31, or any date of this format, really.

Comment: Perhaps my regex analyzer was a bit glitchy.  I'd remove my downvote, but you'd need to edit your question.

Comment: The vote is locked until it's edited.  But let's not get too chatty here, shall we? ;)